# How does this regularization code affect loss?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, regularized

I have seen some learning with convolution neural network code. I do not understand the next part of this code.

```py
loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.nn.l2_loss(tf.subtract(train_output, train_gt)))
    for w in weights:
        loss += tf.nn.l2_loss(w)*1e-4
```

The first line is understandable. It compares the learned result with the label and then represents the square of the difference. And this is the definition of loss. But I do not understand the latter code: `for w in weights:`!!

Here `w` is a list of 10 weights and biases. So `len(w)` is `20(w10 + b10)`. But why does this code calculate the square of `w` and multiply it by `1e-4` to add to the loss?

Is it a necessary for the course of learning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the formula that you have:

[image]

1. `tf.subtract(train_output, train_gt)` does element-wise subtraction between two tensors `train_output` and `train_gt`.
2. `tf.nn.l2_loss(tf.subtract(train_output, train_gt))` computes the l2-norm of the resulted tensor from (1).
3. `tf.reduce_sum(tf.nn.l2_loss(tf.subtract(train_output, train_gt)))` performs reduction sum over all dimensions (e.g. multiple samples in a batch that you have - `N` samples in the formula).
4. `for w in weights: loss += tf.nn.l2_loss(w)*1e-4` adds l2-regularization term (squared sum of all l2-normalized weights in your model).

*But why does this code calculate the square of w and multiply by 1e-4 to add to the loss? Is it a necessary course for learning?*

It punishes the large values of your weights and limits your solution (in terms of weights) to some bounded region. *Is it necessary?* Sometimes yes, and sometimes no. There is no short answer. Start with reading this:

- [Tikhonov regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tikhonov_regularization) in wikipedia
- [Pattern Recognition and
  Machine Learning](http://users.isr.ist.utl.pt/~wurmd/Livros/school/Bishop%20-%20Pattern%20Recognition%20And%20Machine%20Learning%20-%20Springer%20%202006.pdf) by Bishop

Comment: I think he wants more elaboration on tf.nn.l2_loss(w)*1e-4, perhaps in terms of the fundamental of the loss function update.

Comment: That's the answer I want! Thank you very very much!
Is it ok to delete that code?

Comment: @ddjfjfjdjfiejdn, Glad to help. What code are you talking about?

Comment: for w in weights:
        loss += tf.nn.l2_loss(w)*1e-4 <-- this :D

Comment: @ddjfjfjdjfiejdn, Try with and without. It may help or not, depends on the model, data e.t.c. Use it if it reduces error.